# iOS: How to pass first view controller label data of table view cell to textView of second view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uitextview

I am working on an app in which i want to show my table view cell label data of first view controller to the textView of second view controller when click on the button. I have implemented the code but when i click on button the textView of second view becomes blank. Kindly suggest me where i am doing mistake in the following code i have tried many times but couldn't succeeded.

[image: First View Controller]

[image: Second View Controller]

First View Controller:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.jobPostedTableView.dataSource = self;

    //Slide Navigation
    [self.sideNavigation addTarget:[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] action:@selector(toggleLeftMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    WebManager *manager = [WebManager sharedInstance];
    [manager getJobPostedWithCompletionBlock:^(id response){
        NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)response;

        // Read data from JSON
        NSDictionary *responseObject = [dictionary objectForKey:@"response"];
        NSLog(@"The Array%@",responseObject);

        self.bids = [responseObject objectForKey:@"bids"];
        self.job_description = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_description"];
        self.job_id = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_id"];
        self.job_completed = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_completed"];
        self.job_latitude = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_latitude"];
        self.job_longitude = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_longitude"];
        self.job_priority = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_priority"];
        self.job_start_date = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_start_date"];
        self.job_title = [responseObject objectForKey:@"job_title"];

        [self.jobPostedTableView reloadData];
    }];

    self.reversedGeocodes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        }

   #pragma mark - TableView Data Source

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        return [self.job_title count];
    }

    - (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableview:(UITableView *)tableView
    {
        return 1;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"JobTableViewCell";
        JobTableViewCell *cell = (JobTableViewCell *)[self.jobPostedTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) {

            cell = [[JobTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        // Comparing array string to display an urgent image
        if ([[self.job_priority objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
             isEqualToString:@"urgent"]) {
            cell.urgentLabel.hidden = NO;
        } else {
                cell.urgentLabel.hidden = YES;
        }
        // Condition whether job completed is open or closed
        if ([[self.job_completed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
             isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            cell.jobStatus.text = @"Open";
            [cell.jobStatus setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(84/255.f) green:(56/255.f) blue:(255/255.f) alpha:1.0f]];
            cell.flagImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jobPosted_opened.PNG"];
        } else {
            cell.jobStatus.text = @"Closed";
            [cell.jobStatus setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(179/255.f) green:(179/255.f) blue:(180/255.f) alpha:1.0f]];
            cell.flagImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"jobPosted_closed.PNG"];
        }

        cell.jobTitle.text = [self.job_title objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.jobContent.text = [self.job_description objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.bidsLabel.text = [[self.bids objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]stringValue];
        // Latitude and Longitude

        float lat = [self.job_latitude[indexPath.row] floatValue];
        float lng = [self.job_longitude[indexPath.row] floatValue];

        [self locationNameWithLat:lat
                              lng:lng
                completionHandler:^(NSString *locationName, NSError *error) {
                    cell.locationJob.text = locationName;
                }];


        return cell;

    }

- (IBAction)onClickJobButton:(id)sender {

    JobDetailsViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"JobDetailsViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.jobPostedTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    JobDetailsViewController *jobDetailsController = [[JobDetailsViewController alloc]init];
    jobDetailsController.jobDetailView = [self.job_description objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Second View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
WebManager *manager = [WebManager sharedInstance];
NSString *user_name = manager.completeName;
self.nameLabel.text = user_name;
self.jobtextView.text = self.jobDetailView;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using segues, you can send the text using prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME_HERE"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourSecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass labelData which is a string
        [vc setTextString:labelData];
    }
}
```

And don't forget to declare the string  property in your `SecondViewController.h`

```
   @property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *textString;
```